# C++ Builder - program end error and localization error

Tags: error-handling, localization, c++builder

I have a problem with a program I have done with Embarcadero C++ Builder.

Part one:
I want to make stand-alone .exe file, and according to that i have disabled "link with dynamic RTL" and disabled "link with runtime packages". But, every time i end my program, I get an error "Abnormal program termination". I've invstigated that and found a partial solution. When I enable link with runtime packages, that error does not appear, but .exe file won't run on PC which don't have C++ builder installed, because some .bpl files missing. So, for now, I have two possibilities: to have "Abnormal program termination" error, or not to have, functional .exe file for all PCs. Except for that error, my program works perfectly.

Part two:
I made fully functional program with 3 units, and I want to translate it on english language using resource DLL wizard. I can preview translated form, but I can't build it, because it say Error but I can't see any more details about error. I really don't know how is it possible to have working program with no errors, and localized version to have an error. I got the advice to do "clean all" and then "build all" but I can't even clean all because of that error.

I really don't know what to do anymore, I am struggling with those problems for a week now and I really hope that someone can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: I added slow winapi workaround for `ini.h` file for the `language.h` I tested it and it works (but slowly) so you do not need to code anything. I also added some info on how to make this work. I hit the 30KB limit already so I can not add any more stuff

Comment: @DinoCro you have asked two separate and unrelated questions in one post. Per StackOverflow policies, they should have been asked in separate posts. 1 question per post, please. Since your localization question has been addressed here, I suggest you remove the portion about making a standalone EXE and post that as a new question by itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Localization**

   Not sure if your localization tool is suited for Borland/Embarcadero apps (it might be just for **MSVC++** apps which might be the problem).

   I do localization on my own (as I needed custom stuff like internal messages and tables translation. So I coded a ~55 KByte parser that takes `*.h,*.cpp,*.dfm` of all windows as input and creates `*.ini` file and `*.h` that will read the selected language ini and translate all forms to it (`Caption,Hint,...`) then just for each new language I copy the ini and translate the strings. This way I can switch languages on the run without any **DLL** or restart needed and customers can add new languages on their own without the need for source code or programming skills.

   Can not share the code however as it uses some non sharable (corporate) libs of mine for strings,dynamic lists and fast ini file access (they are included in the 55 KByte estimate) but I can share the executable (win32 standalone compiled in **BDS2006** and for **VCL BDS2006** formatting of code):

   - [Form decode tool v2.70](https://ulozto.net/!wsfGvPtJyj4B/form-decode-2-70-exe-zip#_ga=2.175544673.27122962.1526803289-2128131872.1509737289)

   Use the slow download (it is free without registration). I even add one window in the formulars for testing. You just run the exe and when done use the files from output. However the outputed source files use the fast ini file access (I can not share) so you would need to encode that (or replace with your style access). Here **slow** winapi based workaround for my **ini.h** that shoudl work:

   ```cpp
   #ifndef _ini_h
   #define _ini_h
   class inifile
    {
    public:
    AnsiString section,filename;

    // inline
    inifile()   {close();}
    inifile(inifile& a) { *this=a; }
    ~inifile()  {close();}
    inifile* operator = (const inifile *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //inifile* operator = (const inifile &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    int open(AnsiString name) // open ini file
        {
        close();
        if (FileExists(name)) { filename=name; return 1; }
        return 0;
        }
    void close() // close ini file
        {
        filename="";
        section="";
        }
    int sec_getid(const AnsiString &sec, bool _add) // select section to work with ignoring the returned ID
        {
        section=sec;
        return 0;
        }
    AnsiString key_get(int section_id,const AnsiString &key,const AnsiString &def) // read key from section of ini with default value
        {
        if (filename=="") return def;
        char dest[1024]; AnsiString val;
        GetPrivateProfileString(section.c_str(),key.c_str(),def.c_str(),dest,1024,filename.c_str());
        val=dest; return val;
        }
    };
   #endif
   ```

   So the app has 3 folders:

   1. **formulars**

      put all the `*.h,*.cpp;*.dfm` files of your forms here. The parsing of `*.h` is stopping on `public:  (skip user declarations)` to prevent collisions with user code. You can also add comments to end of component line:

      ```cpp
      // LANGUAGE_SKIP_CAPT
      // LANGUAGE_SKIP_TEXT
      // LANGUAGE_SKIP_HINT
      ```

      or any combination to prevent translation is messing with it.
   2. **messages**

      Ignore this it is for `*.cpp` source files with internal messages `_messages[]`to translate must be properly encoded using markers in comments like this:

      ```cpp
      AnsiString _messages[_msg_enum_end+1]=
        {
        //  LANGUAGE_MSG000_TEXT_BEG
        "Error: message id out of range !!!",
        "OpenGL FBO support is missing !!! ... switching to simplified graphics",
        "OpenGL VBO support is missing !!! ... switching to simplified graphics",
        "Sorry: ATI graphic card detected !!! ... switching to simplified graphics",
        "Sorry: ATI Radeon HD 5450 graphic card detected !!! ... disabling preview features",
        "Done.",
        //  LANGUAGE_MSG000_TEXT_END
        "",
        ""
        };
      ```
   3. **output**

      the app here outputs 4 files

      - **init.h** can ignore this it is just init/exit load/stroing of window state
      - **init.ini** ini file for the init can ignore this
        into app ini.
      - **language.h** this is what you want it is the translation routine
      - **english.ini** translation ini file using current window texts

      Here example of generated `language.h`:

      ```cpp
      #include <math.h>
      #include "ini.h" // use the ini.h above

      void language_init(AnsiString name)
        {
        int sec;
        inifile ini;
        ini.open(name);
        sec=ini.sec_getid("Twin_EditorSetup",true);
        win_EditorSetup->ck_specchar->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_ck_specchar","Special chars.");
        win_EditorSetup->ck_specchar->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_ck_specchar","View special characters on/off");
        win_EditorSetup->cb_colors->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_cb_colors","Select color for editing");
        win_EditorSetup->ed_tabs->Text   =ini.key_get(sec,"T_ed_tabs","1");
        win_EditorSetup->ed_tabs->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_ed_tabs","Tabulator size");
        win_EditorSetup->ck_smart->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_ck_smart","Smart eol");
        win_EditorSetup->ck_smart->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_ck_smart","Delete empty space at end of edited line");
        win_EditorSetup->RadioGroup1->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_RadioGroup1","");
        win_EditorSetup->RadioGroup1->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_RadioGroup1","");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol1310->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_rb_eol1310","CR LF");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol1310->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_rb_eol1310","EOL CR LF 13 10");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol13->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_rb_eol13","CR");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol13->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_rb_eol13","EOL CR 13");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol10->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_rb_eol10","LF");
        win_EditorSetup->rb_eol10->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_rb_eol10","EOL LF 10");
        win_EditorSetup->txt_tabs->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_txt_tabs","TAB:");
        win_EditorSetup->txt_tabs->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_txt_tabs","");
        win_EditorSetup->pan_color->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,"C_pan_color","");
        win_EditorSetup->pan_color->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,"H_pan_color","Pick color");
        sec=ini.sec_getid("Global",true);
        ini.close();
        }
      ```

   so in your main app form cpp include `language.h` **but after its pointer is declared** (after line like `TForm1 *Form1;` ) otherwise you will get access violation erros. Now call `language_init` with selected language ini file on any language change or Apps init like this:

   ```
   if (Form1->Visible) language_init(ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName)+"english.ini");
   ```

   you need to specify full path if winapi is used for the `ini.h` !!!
2. **Packages**

   Hard to say without **MCVE**. You most likely use non standard 3th party package and or have a bug in the code. My bet is you got **memory leaks** which tend to make a such errors time to time (especially on exit of app) try to use **CodeGuard** in the Project options which will show you runtime errors and allow you to debug them much better but it will not work for huge projects. Also if you are on older compiler or need to debug the memory leaks see these:

   - [traceback a pointer in c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20565511/2521214)
   - [BDS 2006 C++ hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214)

   They might solve your issues (even those you did not know of yet)

**P.S.**

If you're interested here is the main source for this tool (but without the supporting `*.h` files it will not work but you can see how it work in case you want to encode this on your own:

```cpp
//--- Formular decoder storage class ver 2.40 -------------------------------

#ifndef _frm_decode_h
#define _frm_decode_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _frm_cmp_prop_none    =0x00000000;
// language properties
const int _frm_cmp_prop_capt    =0x00000001;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_text    =0x00000002;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_hint    =0x00000004;
// ini properties
const int _frm_cmp_prop_align   =0x00010000;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_pos     =0x00020000;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_check   =0x00040000;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_down    =0x00080000;
const int _frm_cmp_prop_page    =0x00100000;

class _frm_component
    {
public:
    AnsiString name;        // name in C++
    int prop;               // component class enum
    int action;             // if true do not save/load by language
    };
_frm_component frm_component[]=
    {
    // standard
    "TMenuItem"         ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_check,0,
    "TLabel"            ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TEdit"             ,_frm_cmp_prop_text|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TMemo"             ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TButton"           ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TCheckBox"         ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_check,0,
    "TRadioButton"      ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_check,0,
    "TListBox"          ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TComboBox"         ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TScrollBar"        ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_pos  ,0,
    "TGroupBox"         ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TRadioGroup"       ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TPanel"            ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TAction"           ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    // additional
    "TBitBtn"           ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TSpeedButton"      ,_frm_cmp_prop_capt|_frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_down ,0,
    "TStringGrid"       ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TCategoryButtons"  ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    // win32
    "TProgressBar"      ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    // system
    "TPaintBox"         ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    // win3.1
    "TTabbedNotebook"   ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align|_frm_cmp_prop_page ,0,
    "TFileListBox"      ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TDirectoryListBox" ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "TDriveComboBox"    ,                   _frm_cmp_prop_hint|_frm_cmp_prop_align                    ,0,
    "",0,0
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class frm_decode
    {
public:
    AnsiString form;            // formular class name in C++
    struct _component:_frm_component
        {
        // language properties
        AnsiString text,hint;
        // init properties
        AnsiString align;       // -only for internal init purposes
        AnsiString checked,down,position,left,top,width,height;

        int skip;               // znacky

        void reset()
            {
            text="";
            hint="";
            align="alNone";
            checked="False";
            down="False";
            position="1";
            left="0";
            top="0";
            width="1";
            height="1";
            skip=0;
            }
        };
    struct _message { AnsiString id,txt; };
    List<_component> cmp;
    List<_message> msg;

    frm_decode(){ reset(); }
    void reset()     { form=""; cmp.reset(); msg.reset(); }
    void load_form(AnsiString file);                    // load formular (file.h, file.dfm)
    void load_msg(AnsiString file);                     // load messages (file.h, file.cpp)
    void save_lang_ini(inifile &ini);                   // save language to ini
    void save_init_ini(inifile &ini);                   // save initialisation to ini
    void save_lang_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end=true);  // save language loader (C++) to txt
    void save_init_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end=true);  // save init loader (C++) to txt
    void save_exit_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end=true);  // save exit saver (C++) to txt
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::load_form(AnsiString file)
    {
    // nepodporuje "/* ... */"
    int hnd,adr,siz,i,j,l,e,_skip;
    AnsiString lin,s,s0,ss;
    _component a;
    BYTE *txt;
    reset();

    // load list of components from: file.h
    hnd=FileOpen(file+".h",fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return;
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    txt=new BYTE[siz];
    if (txt==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return; }
    FileRead(hnd,txt,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);
    for (adr=0;adr<siz;)
        {
        lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true);
        l=lin.Length();

        for (_skip=0;i<=l;) // osetri zacky este pred odrezanim pokecu
            {
            s=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
            if (s=="LANGUAGE_SKIP_CAPT") _skip|=_frm_cmp_prop_capt;
            if (s=="LANGUAGE_SKIP_TEXT") _skip|=_frm_cmp_prop_text;
            if (s=="LANGUAGE_SKIP_HINT") _skip|=_frm_cmp_prop_hint;
            }

        if (str_is_mask(lin,"*//*")) { s=lin; lin=""; for (i=1;i<l;i++) if ((s[i]=='/')&&(s[i+1]=='/')) break; else lin+=char(s[i]); l=lin.Length(); }
        s=""; s0=""; e=0;
        for (i=1;i<=l;)
            {
            s0=s;
            s=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
            if (s=="private:")  // stop processing for non formular symbols
                {
                adr=siz; break;
                }

            if (!e) { e=1; continue; }
            if (s0=="class")
                {
                form=s;
                continue;
                }
            if (s!="")
             for (j=0;;j++)
                {
                if (frm_component[j].name=="") break;
                if (frm_component[j].name==s0)
                    {
                    a.reset();
                    a.name="";
                    if (s[1]!='*') s=" "+s;
                    for (int q=2;q<=s.Length();q++) a.name+=s[q];
                    a.prop=frm_component[j].prop;
                    a.action=0;
                    a.skip=_skip;
                    cmp.add(a);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    delete txt;

    // load component properties from: file.dfm
    int cmpid=-1;
    hnd=FileOpen(file+".dfm",fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return;
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    txt=new BYTE[siz];
    if (txt==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return; }
    FileRead(hnd,txt,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);
    for (adr=0;adr<siz;)
        {
        lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true);
        l=lin.Length();

        for (i=1;i<=l;i++)  // if cutted '' line then continue
         if (lin[i]>32)
            {
            if (lin[i]!='\'') i=-1;
            break;
            }
        if (i<0) { s=""; s0=""; e=0; }  // else new line
        for (i=1;i<=l;)
            {
            int q=1;
            if (s!="")
             if (s[1]=='\'')
                {
                if (s[s.Length()]!='\'')
                    {
                    s+=" "+str_load_str(lin,i,true);
                    if (s[s.Length()]!='\'') continue;
                    }
                q=0;
                }
            if (q)
                {
                int qqq=0;  // handle cutted '' line
                ss=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
                if ((s0!="")&&((ss!="")&&(ss[1]=='\''))) { qqq=1; s+=ss; }
                if ((s0!="")&&(ss=="+"))                 { qqq=1; }
                if (!qqq) { s0=s; s=ss; }

                if (s!="")
                 if (s[1]=='\'')
                  if (s[s.Length()]!='\'')
                  e=0;
                }
/*          // odstran ''
            if (s!="")
             if (s[1]=='\'')
              if (s[s.Length()]=='\'')
                { ss=""; for (q=2;q<s.Length();q++) ss+=s[q]; s=ss; }
*/
            if (!e) { e=1; continue; }
            if (s!="")
            if (s0=="object")
                {
                cmpid=-1;
                if (s[s.Length()]==':')
                    {
                    AnsiString t=s;
                    s=""; for (j=1;j<t.Length();j++) s+=char(t[j]);
                    }
                for (j=0;j<cmp.num;j++)
                 if (cmp[j].name==s)
                    {
                    cmpid=j;
                    break;
                    }
                continue;
                }
            if (cmpid<0) continue;

            char aa;
            bool tt;
            int ii,cc,ll=s.Length();
            if (ll>0)
                {
                ss="";
                tt=false;
                for (ii=1;ii<=ll;ii++)
                    {
                    aa=s[ii];
                    if (aa=='\'') { tt=!tt; continue; }
                    if (tt)     { ss+=aa; continue; }
                    if (aa!='#'){ ss+=aa; continue; }
                    cc=0;
                    for (ii++;ii<=ll;ii++)
                        {
                        aa=s[ii];
                        if (aa=='\'') { ii--; break; }
                        if (aa< '0') { ii--; break; }
                        if (aa> '9') { ii--; break; }
                        cc*=10; cc+=aa-'0';
                        }
                    ss+=char(cc);
                    }
                s=ss;
                }

            if (s0=="Action"  ) cmp[cmpid].action=1;
            if (s0=="Caption" ) cmp[cmpid].text=s;
            if (s0=="Text"    ) cmp[cmpid].text=s;
            if (s0=="Hint"    ) cmp[cmpid].hint=s;

            if (s0=="Align"   ) cmp[cmpid].align=s;
            if (s0=="Checked" ) cmp[cmpid].checked=s;
            if (s0=="Down"    ) cmp[cmpid].down=s;
            if (s0=="Position") cmp[cmpid].position=s;
            if (s0=="Left"    ) cmp[cmpid].left=s;
            if (s0=="Top"     ) cmp[cmpid].top=s;
            if (s0=="Width"   ) cmp[cmpid].width=s;
            if (s0=="Height"  ) cmp[cmpid].height=s;
            }
        }
    delete txt;


    // load list of messages from: file.cpp
    load_msg(file+".cpp");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::load_msg(AnsiString file)
    {
    // nepodporuje "/* ... */"
    int hnd,adr,siz,i,l,e;
    AnsiString lin,s;
    BYTE *txt;

    hnd=FileOpen(file,fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return;
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    txt=new BYTE[siz];
    if (txt==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return; }
    FileRead(hnd,txt,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);

    e=msg.num;
    for (adr=0;adr<siz;)
        {
        lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true);
        l=lin.Length();
        for (i=1;i<=l;)
            {
            s=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
            if (s=="_msg_enum_beg")
             for (;adr<siz;)
                {
                lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true);
                l=lin.Length();
                for (i=1;i<=l;)
                    {
                    s=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
                    if (s=="_msg_enum_end") { adr=siz; i=l+1; break; }
                    if (str_is_mask(s,"_msg*"))
                        {
                        _message m;
                        m.id=s;
                        m.txt="";
                        msg.add(m);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    for (adr=0;adr<siz;)
        {
        lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true);
        l=lin.Length();
        for (i=1;i<=l;)
            {
            s=str_load_str(lin,i,true);
            if (s=="_messages[_msg_enum_end+1]")
             for (;adr<siz;)
                {
                if (e>=msg.num) break;
                s="";
                for (;adr<siz;adr++)
                 if (txt[adr]=='"')
                    {
                    adr++;
                    for (;adr<siz;adr++)
                     if (txt[adr]=='"')
                        {
                        adr++;
                        msg[e].txt=s;
                        e++;
                        break;
                        }
                     else s+=char(txt[adr]);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    delete txt;

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::save_lang_ini(inifile &ini)
    {
    int i,p,s,sec;
    AnsiString key,val;
    sec=ini.sec_getid(form,true);
    for (i=0;i<msg.num;i++) ini.key_set(sec,msg[i].id,msg[i].txt);

    for (i=0;i<cmp.num;i++)
        {
        if (cmp[i].action) continue;
        key=cmp[i].name;
        p=cmp[i].prop;
        s=cmp[i].skip;
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_capt)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_capt)==0)) ini.key_set(sec,"C_"+key,cmp[i].text);
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_text)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_text)==0)) ini.key_set(sec,"T_"+key,cmp[i].text);
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_hint)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_hint)==0)) ini.key_set(sec,"H_"+key,cmp[i].hint);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::save_init_ini(inifile &ini)
    {
    int i,p,sec;
    AnsiString key,val;
    sec=ini.sec_getid(form,true);
    for (i=0;i<cmp.num;i++)
        {
        if (cmp[i].action) continue;
        key=cmp[i].name;
        p=cmp[i].prop;

        if (cmp[i].align=="alLeft")     ini.key_set(sec,"XS_"+key,cmp[i].width);
        if (cmp[i].align=="alRight")    ini.key_set(sec,"XS_"+key,cmp[i].width);
        if (cmp[i].align=="alTop")      ini.key_set(sec,"YS_"+key,cmp[i].height);
        if (cmp[i].align=="alBottom")   ini.key_set(sec,"YS_"+key,cmp[i].height);
        if (cmp[i].align=="alClient")
            {
            }
        if (cmp[i].align=="alNone")
            {
/*
            ini.key_set(sec,"X0_"+key,cmp[i].left);
            ini.key_set(sec,"Y0_"+key,cmp[i].top);
            ini.key_set(sec,"XS_"+key,cmp[i].width);
            ini.key_set(sec,"YS_"+key,cmp[i].height);
*/
            }
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_check   )!=0) ini.key_set(sec,"CHK_"+key,(cmp[i].checked=="True")?"1":"0");
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_down    )!=0) ini.key_set(sec,"DWN_"+key,(cmp[i].down   =="True")?"1":"0");
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_pos     )!=0) ini.key_set(sec,"POS_"+key, cmp[i].position                );
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::save_lang_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end)
    {
    int i,p,s;
    AnsiString cpp,lin,key,frm,tabl,endl;
    tabl=char(9); endl=char(13); endl+=char(10);
    cpp="";
    if (txt=="")
        {
        lin="";
        lin+="#include <math.h>"+endl;
        lin+="#include \"ini.h\""+endl+endl;
        lin+="void language_init(AnsiString name)"+endl;
        lin+=tabl+"{"+endl;
        lin+=tabl+"int sec;"+endl;
        lin+=tabl+"inifile ini;"+endl;
        lin+=tabl+"ini.open(name);"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    frm=""; for (i=2;i<=form.Length();i++) frm+=form[i];
    cpp+=endl;
    cpp+=tabl+"sec=ini.sec_getid(\""+form+"\",true);"+endl;
    for (i=0;i<msg.num;i++)
        {
        lin=tabl+"_messages[";
        if (i<100) lin+=" ";
        if (i<10) lin+=" ";
        lin+=i;
        lin+="]=ini.key_get(sec,\""+msg[i].id+"\",\""+msg[i].txt+"\");"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    for (i=0;i<cmp.num;i++)
        {
        if (cmp[i].action) continue;
        key=cmp[i].name;
        p=cmp[i].prop;
        s=cmp[i].skip;
        lin="";
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_capt)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_capt)==0)) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Caption=ini.key_get(sec,\"C_"+key+"\",\""+cmp[i].text+"\");"+endl;
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_text)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_text)==0)) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Text   =ini.key_get(sec,\"T_"+key+"\",\""+cmp[i].text+"\");"+endl;
        if ((int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_hint)!=0)&&(int(s&_frm_cmp_prop_hint)==0)) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Hint   =ini.key_get(sec,\"H_"+key+"\",\""+cmp[i].hint+"\");"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    if (end)
        {
        lin=endl;
        lin+=tabl+"ini.close();"+endl;
        lin+=tabl+"}"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    txt+=cpp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::save_init_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end)
    {
    int i,p;
    AnsiString cpp,lin,key,frm,tabl,endl,endlx;
    tabl=char(9); endl=char(13); endl+=char(10); endlx="\\"+endl;
    cpp="";
    if (txt=="")
        {
        lin="";
        lin+="//---------------------------------------------------------------------------"+endl;
        lin+="#include <math.h>"+endl;
        lin+="#include \"ini.h\""+endl;
        lin+="//---------------------------------------------------------------------------"+endl;
        lin+="#define _def_program_init(name) for(;;)"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"{"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"int sec;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"inifile ini;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"ini.open(name);"+endlx;
//      lin+=tabl+"if (!ini.open(name)) break;"+endlx;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    frm=""; for (i=2;i<=form.Length();i++) frm+=form[i];
    cpp+=tabl+"sec=ini.sec_getid(\""+form+"\",true);"+endlx;
    for (i=0;i<cmp.num;i++)
        {
        if (cmp[i].action) continue;
        key=cmp[i].name;
        p=cmp[i].prop;
        lin="";

        if (cmp[i].align=="alLeft")   lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Width =ini.key_geti(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].width +");"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alRight")  lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Width =ini.key_geti(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].width +");"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alTop")    lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Height=ini.key_geti(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].height+");"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alBottom") lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Height=ini.key_geti(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].height+");"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alClient")
            {
            }
        if (cmp[i].align=="alNone")
            {
/*
            lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Left  =ini.key_geti(sec,\"X0_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].left  +");"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Top   =ini.key_geti(sec,\"Y0_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].top   +");"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Width =ini.key_geti(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].width +");"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Height=ini.key_geti(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].height+");"+endlx;
*/
            }
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_check   )!=0) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Checked =ini.key_geti(sec,\"CHK_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].checked +");"+endlx;
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_down    )!=0) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Down    =ini.key_geti(sec,\"DWN_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].down    +");"+endlx;
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_pos     )!=0) lin+=tabl+frm+"->"+key+"->Position=ini.key_geti(sec,\"POS_"+key+"\","+cmp[i].position+");"+endlx;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    if (end)
        {
        lin+=tabl+"ini.close();"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"break;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"}"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    txt+=cpp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frm_decode::save_exit_cpp(AnsiString &txt,bool end)
    {
    int i,p;
    AnsiString cpp,lin,key,frm,tabl,endl,endlx;
    tabl=char(9); endl=char(13); endl+=char(10); endlx="\\"+endl;
    cpp="";
    if (txt=="")
        {
        lin+="//---------------------------------------------------------------------------"+endl;
        lin+="#define _def_program_exit(name) for(;;)"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"{"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"int sec;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"inifile ini;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"ini.open(name);"+endlx;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    frm=""; for (i=2;i<=form.Length();i++) frm+=form[i];
    cpp+=tabl+"sec=ini.sec_getid(\""+form+"\",true);"+endlx;
    for (i=0;i<cmp.num;i++)
        {
        if (cmp[i].action) continue;
        key=cmp[i].name;
        p=cmp[i].prop;
        lin="";
        if (cmp[i].align=="alLeft")   lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Width );"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alRight")  lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Width );"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alTop")    lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Height);"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alBottom") lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Height);"+endlx;
        if (cmp[i].align=="alClient")
            {
            }
        if (cmp[i].align=="alNone")
            {
/*
            lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"X0_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Left  );"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"Y0_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Top   );"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"XS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Width );"+endlx;
            lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"YS_"+key+"\","+frm+"->"+key+"->Height);"+endlx;
*/
            }
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_check   )!=0) lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"CHK_"+key+"\",int("+frm+"->"+key+"->Checked));"+endlx;
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_down    )!=0) lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"DWN_"+key+"\",int("+frm+"->"+key+"->Down   ));"+endlx;
        if (int(p&_frm_cmp_prop_pos     )!=0) lin+=tabl+"ini.key_set(sec,\"POS_"+key+"\",    "+frm+"->"+key+"->Position);"+endlx;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    if (end)
        {
        lin+=tabl+"ini.save(name);"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"ini.close();"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"break;"+endlx;
        lin+=tabl+"}"+endl;
        lin+="//---------------------------------------------------------------------------"+endl;
        cpp+=lin;
        }
    txt+=cpp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```