# Image output in C

Tags: c, turbo-c

Quick question, is there a way to show an image(ex. bmp) from file using C? It's not in graphics.h apparently, and I can't use Allegro because it does not support Borland(or so I've read). I need to use the very old compiler for a school project. I would like to ask if anyone had any experience of doing this using other libraries? If yes, which library was it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Graphics are not part of C; any graphics libraries are specific to a platform.  When compiler/environment you are using, or have available, will determine how you might accomplish this, so you'll need to spell them out.

Comment: We'll be using Turbo C on Win7. And our little project is plotting points on the world map. We need to have the map image displayed as we plot the points, but we don't know how to display an image. It sounds so dumb, I wish I knew the answer to this.

Comment: @CIB added answer check it out if I miss something comment me ...

Comment: btw if you use turbo c++ on w7 (BDS2006) like me then it is worth loking at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214 will spare you a lot of headaches ...

Comment: Don't use TurboC++ in 2017 (or even 2014). Use recent standard conforming compilers (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)....) for C11 or C++14.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have visual (windows) borland like Borland C++ builder 3++ or turbo C++ not the MS DOS one. in that case it is quite easy because you can use bitmap which is part of **VCL** so no additional include is needed.

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214) you can find some hints on rendering under borland

now how to visualize picture from file to your window:

```
// this will create and load your bitmap
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
bmp->LoadFromFile("image.bmp");
bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;

// on paint you can draw your image to form,paintbox,another bitmap or whatever...
Form1->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp); // also you can use stretch draw or copy rectangle GDI functions

// before exiting delete the bmp
delete bmp;
```

**[Notes]**

You can also save image by `bmp->SaveToFile("out.bmp");` In case you need **jpg** then add:

```
#include <jpeg.hpp>

TJPEGImage *jpg=new TJPEGImage;
jpg->LoadFromFile("image.jpg");
bmp->Assign(jpg);
delete jpg;
```

this will load **jpg** to your **bmp** also you can save **jpg** as well in the same way. **Beware** older Borlands has a bug in `TJPEGImage` and will crash if the **jpg** resolution is too big**