# Why is happened property write error?

Tags: properties, borland-c++

c++ : Run time error is happened with error message like this:

```
RevStrings1->Height of reading included in error: The property is write-protected.
RevStrings1->Height の読み込中のエラー : プロパティは書き込み禁止です.
```

---

I'm using c++ builder 3.

This source code can be successfully compiled 
setting library, include path and etc.

But run time error is happened.

---

I guess that this problem is about property read & write.

How can I simplly fix the problem ?

A variable `RevStrings1` is created by a class `TRevStrings`.

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef RevStringsH
#define RevStringsH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <Grids.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TRevStrings : public TStringGrid
{
private:
//  void __fastcall SetWidth(int W);
//  int __fastcall GetWidth(void);
//  int FColCount ;
  int FRowCount;
  int FFixedCols ;
  int FFixedRows ;
  int FDefaultColWidth ;
  int FDefaultRowHeight ;
  int FHeight;
//  int FWidth;
  int FScrollBars;
  int FMaxLength;
  bool ColColors[24];

protected:
public:
    __fastcall TRevStrings(TComponent* Owner);
  void __fastcall DrawCellText(TRect ARect,int ALeft,String S);
  virtual void __fastcall DrawCell(int ACol, int ARow,const Windows::TRect &ARect, TGridDrawState AState);
  void __fastcall SetColor_Col(int Col,int Row);
  void __fastcall SetColorFlag(int Col,bool flag);
  bool __fastcall GetColorFlag(int Col);
  void __fastcall SetEditText(int ACol, int ARow,const System::AnsiString Value);
  void __fastcall Clear(bool ALLorONE,int Position);
  void __fastcall DblClick(void);
__published:
//  __property int ColCount = {read = FColCount};//FColCount};
  __property int RowCount = {read=FRowCount};
  __property int FixedCols = {read=FFixedCols};
  __property int FixedRows = {read=FFixedRows};
  __property int DefaultColWidth = {read=FDefaultColWidth};
  __property int DefaultRowHeight = {read=FDefaultRowHeight};
  __property int Height = {read=FHeight};
//  __property int Width = {read=GetWidth,write=SetWidth};
  __property int ScrollBars = {read=FScrollBars};
  __property int MaxLength = {read=FMaxLength,write=FMaxLength};
/*
*/
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: please specify what component class is this and copy here the line of code that created this exception. (Haven't used BCB3 in ages If my memory serves was really buggy more then BCB6.The best from BCB series was BCB5 was using it very long and would still if I haven't been forced by company to BDS2006 which is even better if you know its hick-ups and know how to avoid them)

Comment: A variable 'RevStrings1' is created by a class 'TRevStrings'. But there isn't 'RevStrings1->Height' in my source code. A variable 'RevStrings1->Height' isn't used anywhere. Is this problem about a version of C++ builder ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @TaeungSong added answer with some approaches and explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**never heard of `TRevStrings` before**

so it is either **BCB 3** discontinued stuff (my **BDS2006** does not have it at disposal) or you have some 3th party custom package installed but the header file suggest it is based on `TStringGrid` so if below text does not work for it then you can switch to `TStringGrid` instead.

**in `TStringGrid`**

size properties are accessible normaly:

```cpp
StringGrid1->Height=256;
StringGrid1->Width=128;
```

if you want to have size-able col/rows then do not forget to open Options property and set `goRowSizing,goColSizing` to `true` and starting sizes are `DefaultColWidth,DefaultRowHeight`. Here example of usage

```cpp
// resize the grid
StringGrid1->Height=128;
StringGrid1->Width=256;
// access to Cell AnsiStings
StringGrid1->Cells[0][0]="(0,0)";
StringGrid1->Cells[1][1]="(1,1)";
StringGrid1->Cells[1][2]="(1,2)";
StringGrid1->Cells[2][1]="(2,1)";
// resizing row/col
StringGrid1->RowHeights[0]=15;
StringGrid1->RowHeights[1]=20;
StringGrid1->ColWidths[0]=20;
StringGrid1->ColWidths[1]=15;
```

As your class is derived from this so this should work also for it if not the there are more possibilities:

1. **you have unrelated bug somewhere**

   overwriting what you should not damaging the **C++** engine your App is running on or have memory leak somewhere  or your memory manager is invalidated see

   - [bds 2006 C hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17698102/2521214)

   but that is probably not the case or you are calling **VCL/Winapi** visual stuff from threads.

**To check for all this:**

create empty application, add your `TRevString` and try to set its height on runtime. If no error occurs you have a bug somewhere if error occurs then:

2. **this component is not able to resize on runtime this way**

   try to use functions like `SetSize,SetBounds` instead or place the component on some panel align to Client and resize panel
3. **if even this does not help switch to standard `TStringGrid`**

   you can also try to cast you `RevString` to `StringGrid` first

   ```
   ((TStringGrid*)(RevString1))->Height=25;
   ```
4. **Borland compilers sometimes get weird**

   few times (around 10) over the years I use **BCB/BDS** the compiler sometimes compile wrongly. The app is running but some code gets distorted or discarted so  what helps?

   - close **IDE** or even restart Windows
   - delete all `map,obj,tds` temp files prior to compiling rebuilding
   - sometimes is needed that you add empty line of code or swap 2 lines of code
5. **Identifiers/Names collisions**

   if you name your stuff in similar way to **VCL** functions then you ask for problems usual error is to name function `Draw()` ... (use `draw()` instead and you are fine)
6. **for big projects**

   if you add your source code as new unit to project instead of just include it (it is present in Object Manager) then in big projects you will got big problems. It looks like units are compiled differently then normal included files in units are expected Formulars and other **VCL** stuff components so if you got your own non visual classes as units they sometimes stop working as expected creating weird behavior (even your error could be caused by it).

   I observe this on **BCB5** and **BDS2006**. In **BCB3,BCB4** I did not make big enough projects to spot this and **BCB6** is so buggy so its unusable with big projects anyway. By big projects I mean > 1 MB of pure **C++** code

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory - the `Height` property of the `RevStrings1` object is not allowing its value to be assigned.  This is evident by looking at the declaration of the `Height` property in the `TRevStrings` class:

```
__property int Height = {read=FHeight};
```

`TRevStrings` is going out of its way to make the `Height` property read-only, *overriding* the native read-write `Height` property that is inherited from `TControl`:

```
__property int Height = {read=FHeight, write=SetHeight, nodefault};
```

This is odd for `TRevString` to do, as it is a visual component that needs to be sizable.  Unless it requires a specific height that the user cannot change (in which case declaring the `Height` property as read-only is not the correct way to handle that - the component should override the virtual `SetBounds()` method instead and just ignore any new `Height` value being assigned).

That being said, the reason you see the error at run-time is because the IDE is storing the design-time `Height` value of the `RevStrings1` object in the parent Form's DFM resource at compile-time.  That is why you are not finding any `RevStrings1->Height` in your code - it is coming from the Form Designer instead.  The `TRevStrings` class is not overriding DFM behavior for the `Height` property, so when the VCL's DFM streaming system parses the Form's DFM resource at run-time, it sees the stored `Height` value and detects that the object's `Height` property is actually read-only, and so throws an exception to cancel DFM streaming (and thus the Form's construction).

This is a bug in the `TRevStrings` implementation.  At the very least, if the author had wanted to prevent the `Height` from being streamed (thus preventing the run-time error), the `Height` property should have been declared like this instead:

```
__property Height = {read=FHeight, stored=false};
```

On a side note, *most* of the `TRevStrings` data members (`FColCount`, `FRowCount`, `FFixedCols`, `FFixedRows`, etc) should *never* have been declared at all, but instead should have been inherited from the base `TStringGrid` class.

Whoever wrote this component clearly did not know what they were doing.