# BDS 2006 build executable without external dependencies

Tags: c++, linker, borland-c++

I have BDS 2006 C++ installed on my machine. Now I create simple test VCL program. It runs on my machine without any problem. But while running on other another machine it reports about missing libraries:

- cc3270.dll
- borlndmm.dll

In project options `Linker/Linking/Use dynamic RTL` is unckecked. `Packages/Build with runtime packages` - unchecked. Build configuration - `Release`.

What I do wrong and how to compile without external dependencies or may be to link my exe with these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In BDS 2006 Turbo C++ Explorer I do it like this:

**Project/Options/Linker**

- `Linking/Use dynamic RTL` (unchecked)
- `Linking/No state files` (checked)
- `Package options/Design time and runtime package` (checked)

**Project/Options/Turbo assembler (tasm32)**

- `Packages/Build with runtime packages` (unchecked)

**[Notes]**

- make sure you recompile and rebuild application (I delete all tds,obj,exe files)
- if it does not help:

  - you link the libs manually by some `#pragma link` outside VCL code so the linker is confused...
  - the project options did not save
  - your compiler is messed up and need clearing the pre-compiled header files or moving `#pragma hdrstop`
  - if it is ported project from older BCB version it sometimes corrupt the project file somehow (better is to create new project file and copy it ...)
- I recommend to read [BDS 2006 C++ hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17698102/2521214) to avoid future problems