# Too many initializers error for a simple array in bcc32

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, borland-c++

Compiling the following example

```
struct S {};

int main() {
  S array[1] = { S() };
}
```

with [bcc32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/BCC32.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_32-bit_Command-Line_Compiler) I get the following error:

```
[bcc32 Error] test.cpp(4): E2225 Too many initializers
```

Is it a bug in bcc32 or am I missing something and the above example is not valid C++?

Both Clang and GCC compile this example without problems.

Comment: Seems perfectly valid aggregate initialization to me. I'm not sure if it's the problem here, but I think using `S()` in there wouldn't be technically correct before c++03. Does bcc32 support c++03?

Comment: They claim to support some of the C++11 features such as rvalue references but I couldn't find information about the completeness of C++98/03 support.

Comment: The feature that's needed from c++03 to make that technically correct is *value-initialization*. I'd be very surprised if the compiler didn't support it if it does support C++11 too. Besides, I'm not sure how that applies to an empty object because the technicality is related to copying the object but  there is nothing to copy.

Comment: @vitaut see my answer how to solve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borland **BDS2006** (and possibly newer versions)

has some issues with **default constructor/destructor** for `class` and `struct` inside its C++ engine.

- see [bds 2006 C hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214) for more info.

Adding custom (even empty) **constructor/destructor** solves **many issues** even yours. Try:

```
struct S
    {
    S(){};
    S(S& a){};
    ~S(){};
    S* operator = (const S *a){};
    //S* operator = (const S &a){}; // use this only if you have dynamic allocation members
    };

int main()
    {
    S array[1] = { S() };
    }
```

I tried this in **BDS2006** and it looks like it works (hard to tell without anything inside `struct`) but you can compile and run at least...

I detect this behavior first in **BDS2006** ... haven't really try **BCB6** as it was junk from the start and dismiss it after few days (I think the worst **BCB** ever even beats **BCB3,4**) in **BCB5** was all fine (before **BDS2006** was this my favorite IDE) with this so they must have change the C++ engine (do not confuse with runtime libs !!!).

Adding even empty constructor destructor helps. If you got dynamic allocations you need to handle those of coarse. If you got nested class/struct do not forget to add these also to them too.