# Assignment of values to an array of struct with array inside

Tags: arrays, struct, c++builder

I have this array of struct that contain one array

```
struct pannello_t {
    String nome;
    TLabel* labelNome;
    TShape* ShapeLed[10];
} Moduli[20];
```

I can compile without errors with:

```
Moduli[0].nome = "HCL-IN8";
Moduli[0].labelNome = LabelP1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[0] = Led1P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[1] = Led2P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[2] = Led3P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[3] = Led4P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[4] = Led5P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[5] = Led6P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[6] = Led7P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[7] = Led8P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[8] = Led9P1;
Moduli[0].ShapeLed[9] = Led10P1;
... etc
```

But I am looking for a more compact way, I try this:

```
Moduli[0] = {"HCL-XXX", LabelP3, {Led1P3, Led2P3, Led3P3, Led4P3, Led5P3, Led6P3, Led7P3, Led8P3, Led9P3, Led10P3}  };
```

But the compiler says: `E2188 Expression syntax`. I look on books and google, but I can't find a solution, so I am here to ask help.

Comment: what version of the c++ standard are you using ?

Comment: Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2

Comment: Project - Options - C++ Compiler: Use 'classic' Borland compiler

Comment: Does Moduli[0] = {"HCL-XXX", LabelP3, {&Led1P3, &Led2P3, &Led3P3,...}} work ?

Comment: No. Error: E12188 Expression syntax

Comment: Does Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.1 Berlin support c++ 14 ? My example compiles fine on a c++ 14 compiler.

Comment: I think is Borland BCC64

Comment: @auburg: No, probably not. C++11, AFAIK.

Comment: @auburg no, C++14 is not supported (that will be in the upcoming 10.3 release).  C++Builder's [**clang-based** compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) do support C++11, its **classic** Win32 and OSX compilers do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older Borland/Embarcadero compilers there was a compiler bug which was occasionally causing this. However I found an workaround:

- [bds 2006 C hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214)
- [Too many initializers error for a simple array in bcc32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33867999/2521214)

which among other things also allows to use the assignment like you want again...  However I doubt its still the case with newer compilers but still worth trying.

If that does not work There is still one option I used before I found this workaround. You have to create loading function that returns your `struct` (something like constructor) and then just feed array with it...

Here 2 options (Both working on my BDS2006 C++ and also both can be combined together):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// I assume your VCL form components ...
TLabel *LabelP1; TShape *Led1P1,*Led2P1,*Led3P1,*Led4P1,*Led5P1,*Led6P1,*Led7P1,*Led8P1,*Led9P1,*Led10P1;
TLabel *LabelP2; TShape *Led1P2,*Led2P2,*Led3P2,*Led4P2,*Led5P2,*Led6P2,*Led7P2,*Led8P2,*Led9P2,*Led10P2;
TLabel *LabelP3; TShape *Led1P3,*Led2P3,*Led3P3,*Led4P3,*Led5P3,*Led6P3,*Led7P3,*Led8P3,*Led9P3,*Led10P3;
TLabel *LabelP4; TShape *Led1P4,*Led2P4,*Led3P4,*Led4P4,*Led5P4,*Led6P4,*Led7P4,*Led8P4,*Led9P4,*Led10P4;
TLabel *LabelP5; TShape *Led1P5,*Led2P5,*Led3P5,*Led4P5,*Led5P5,*Led6P5,*Led7P5,*Led8P5,*Led9P5,*Led10P5;
// struct
struct pannello_t
    {
    String nome;
    TLabel* labelNome;
    TShape* ShapeLed[10];
    };
// load function for style 2
pannello_t ld(String nome,TLabel* labelNome,TShape* S0,TShape* S1,TShape* S2,TShape* S3,TShape* S4,TShape* S5,TShape* S6,TShape* S7,TShape* S8,TShape* S9)
    {
    pannello_t a;
    a.nome=nome;
    a.labelNome=labelNome;
    a.ShapeLed[0]=S0;
    a.ShapeLed[1]=S1;
    a.ShapeLed[2]=S2;
    a.ShapeLed[3]=S3;
    a.ShapeLed[4]=S4;
    a.ShapeLed[5]=S5;
    a.ShapeLed[6]=S6;
    a.ShapeLed[7]=S7;
    a.ShapeLed[8]=S8;
    a.ShapeLed[9]=S9;
    return a;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void test()
    {
    // 1. style
    pannello_t A[5]=
        {
        {"HCL-XXX", LabelP1, {Led1P1, Led2P1, Led3P1, Led4P1, Led5P1, Led6P1, Led7P1, Led8P1, Led9P1, Led10P1} },
        {"HCL-XXX", LabelP2, {Led1P2, Led2P2, Led3P2, Led4P2, Led5P2, Led6P2, Led7P2, Led8P2, Led9P2, Led10P2} },
        {"HCL-XXX", LabelP3, {Led1P3, Led2P3, Led3P3, Led4P3, Led5P3, Led6P3, Led7P3, Led8P3, Led9P3, Led10P3} },
        {"HCL-XXX", LabelP4, {Led1P4, Led2P4, Led3P4, Led4P4, Led5P4, Led6P4, Led7P4, Led8P4, Led9P4, Led10P4} },
        {"HCL-XXX", LabelP5, {Led1P5, Led2P5, Led3P5, Led4P5, Led5P5, Led6P5, Led7P5, Led8P5, Led9P5, Led10P5} },
        };
    // 2. style
    pannello_t B[5];
    B[0]=ld("HCL-XXX", LabelP1, Led1P1, Led2P1, Led3P1, Led4P1, Led5P1, Led6P1, Led7P1, Led8P1, Led9P1, Led10P1 );
    B[1]=ld("HCL-XXX", LabelP2, Led1P2, Led2P2, Led3P2, Led4P2, Led5P2, Led6P2, Led7P2, Led8P2, Led9P2, Led10P2 );
    B[2]=ld("HCL-XXX", LabelP3, Led1P3, Led2P3, Led3P3, Led4P3, Led5P3, Led6P3, Led7P3, Led8P3, Led9P3, Led10P3 );
    B[3]=ld("HCL-XXX", LabelP4, Led1P4, Led2P4, Led3P4, Led4P4, Led5P4, Led6P4, Led7P4, Led8P4, Led9P4, Led10P4 );
    B[4]=ld("HCL-XXX", LabelP5, Led1P5, Led2P5, Led3P5, Led4P5, Led5P5, Led6P5, Led7P5, Led8P5, Led9P5, Led10P5 );
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Beware that if you are using the definition inside declaration of your array then the VCL components you are assigning must be already pointing to your created VCL components.** If you can not guarantee it then the only safe options are either feed the array in runtime using style 2 and `ld` function for example in Form constructor or instead of just pointers use pointer of pointer...

Also I saw that some compilers have problems with using struct (not Borland however) in such cases using typedef helps...

```cpp
typedef struct
    {
    String nome;
    TLabel* labelNome;
    TShape* ShapeLed[10];
    } pannello_t;
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option, 1 style,  gave me an error, I did not waste a lot of time and I used the second, 2 style, that is much more compact than my first solution.

Comment: @Livio glad to be of help... I bet the first option (even if my compiler was fine with it) was flagged as error due to fact that on compile time the VCL components are not yet created and/or the conversion from `const char*` to `string` needs another casting/owertyping which is not the case at runtime...