# Can I send a stream from blob data in a database to PlaySound (MMSystem) rather than supplying a file name?

Tags: winapi, audio, c++builder, windows-11, playsound

I need to be able to supply a stand alone system for a medical application that will be distributed free of charge to home users of blood pressure monitors, it is being designed to run off a memory stick and taken to doctors, pharmacists, hospitals, I would like to have a database file of spoken instructions for data entry fields for those who are not computer savvy.

The system is being developed to capture a large amount of observed symptomatic data from the user in the home which can then be taken to a doctor to open in the system and see the observation data as taken at the time for actual review and diagnosis, it is intended for those who are interested in helping themselves by letting their doctors or any other health practitioner understand by knowing what the patient experienced during the pain, feelings and other important information a doctor may rely on that they have identified.

At the moment I have

```
    String file = frmMDI->dlg->InitialDir + "\\sounds\\" + "ObservationDateTimeField.wav";
    speech->Send(file);
```

What this does is speak out the instruction for what is expected in the field when it has received the focus, it works fine as it is but would like to get the wav from the database so there is minimal files being distributed via usb.

in the OnEnter method, speech is a custom control that manages my needs, simply the PlaySound(...) requirement for .wav files, other controls work out how and when to send instruction.

Edit: a
add screen shot of observations window

[Screen capture of main observation entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mSAx.png)

I would like to have this as open source but I have no idea how to get it there, it is a development of ideas spanning 20 years, my code may be left wanting but it all works and has done so for a long time.

How do I go about it, if it can be done?

I have not had time to try too many things like sending a stream instead of a file, playsound works fine from a .wav sound file

Edit: Thanks to Spektre for time and code, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience WAVEIN/WAVEOUT is the best sound api on win for this purpose... DirectSound is(was) buggy and very big latency so I stopped using it for good years ago...

Here my ancient C++ lib I originally wrote for my [oscilloscope,spectral analyzator,signal generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658139/2521214) apps but using it everywhere even in my ZXSpectrum emulator:

**waveout.h:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- WAVE IN/OUT class ver: 4.02 -------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _waveout_h
#define _waveout_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include "fifo.h"
#include "lock.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK wave_in_event(HWAVEIN hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2);
void CALLBACK wave_out_event(HWAVEOUT hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class wave_in
    {
public:
    bool _init,_fifo;
    FIFO<BYTE> fifo;
    WAVEHDR *hdr;
    HWAVEIN hw;
    WAVEFORMATEX buff_format;
    DWORD buff_size;
    DWORD  freq; WORD chanels,bits,samples,buffers;
    BYTE **buff;
    int adr,num;

    void CALLBACK (*event)(HWAVEIN hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2);
//  void (*onreceive)(wave_in *wi,BYTE *data,int size);
    void (__closure *onreceive)(wave_in *wi,BYTE *data,int size);

    wave_in()
        {
        hdr=NULL;
        buff=NULL;
        buffers=0;
        buff_size=0;
        _init=false;
        adr=0;
        num=0;
        event=wave_in_event;
        onreceive=NULL;
        }
    ~wave_in()
        {
        _free();
        }
    wave_in(wave_in& a) { *this=a; }
    wave_in* operator = (const wave_in *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //wave_in* operator = (const wave_in &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void _free()
        {
        adr=0;
        num=0;
        if (_init) { waveInClose(hw); _init=false; }
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        if (buff) for (int i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) mmap_del(buff[i]);
        if (buff) mmap_del(buff);
        if (hdr ) mmap_del(hdr );
        #endif
        if (buff)
            {
            for (int i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) delete[] buff[i];
            delete[] buff;
            buff=NULL;
            }
        if (hdr) { delete[] hdr; hdr=NULL; }
        }
    void init(DWORD _freq,WORD _chanels,WORD _bits,WORD _samples,WORD _buffers=5)
        {
        int i,ret;
        _free();
        buffers=_buffers;
        if (buffers<1) buffers=1;
        hdr=new WAVEHDR[buffers];
        buff=new BYTE*[buffers];
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        if (hdr ) mmap_new(hdr ,buffers*sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (buff) mmap_new(buff,buffers*sizeof(BYTE*));
        #endif
        freq    =_freq;
        chanels =_chanels;
        bits    =_bits;
        samples =_samples;
        buff_size=(chanels*bits*samples)>>3;
        samples=(buff_size<<3)/(chanels*bits);

        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++) buff[i]=new BYTE[buff_size];
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) mmap_new(buff[i],buff_size);
        #endif

        buff_format.wFormatTag      =WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;       // set buffer format
        buff_format.nChannels       =chanels;
        buff_format.nSamplesPerSec  =freq;
        buff_format.wBitsPerSample  =bits;
        buff_format.cbSize          =0;
        buff_format.nAvgBytesPerSec =(freq*chanels*bits)>>3;
        buff_format.nBlockAlign     =(chanels*bits)>>3;
        if (event) ret=waveInOpen(&hw,WAVE_MAPPER,&buff_format,(DWORD_PTR)event,(DWORD_PTR)this,CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
        else       ret=waveInOpen(&hw,WAVE_MAPPER,&buff_format,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL);
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveInGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            return;
            }
        WAVEHDR hdr0;
        hdr0.dwBufferLength=buff_size;
        hdr0.dwUser=0;
        hdr0.dwFlags=0;
        hdr0.dwLoops=0;
        hdr0.lpNext=NULL;
        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++)
            {
            hdr[i]=hdr0;
            hdr[i].lpData=buff[i];
            }
        _init=true;
        }
    void add()
        {
        if (!_init) return;
        int i,ret;
        BYTE *p;
        p=buff[adr];
        ret=waveInPrepareHeader(hw,&hdr[adr],sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveInGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            return;
            }
        waveInAddBuffer(hw,&hdr[adr],sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveInGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            return;
            }
        adr++;
        if (adr>=buffers) adr=0;
        num++;
        }
    void start()
        {
        if (!_init) return;
        while (num<buffers) add();
        waveInStart(hw);
        }
    void stop()
        {
        if (!_init) return;
        waveInStop(hw);
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class wave_out:public multi_lock
    {
public:
    bool _init,_fifo;
    FIFO<BYTE> fifo;
    WAVEHDR *hdr;
    HWAVEOUT hw;
    WAVEFORMATEX buff_format;
    DWORD buff_size;
    DWORD  freq; WORD chanels,bits,samples,buffers;
    BYTE **buff;
    int adr,num,err;

    void CALLBACK (*event)(HWAVEOUT hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2);

    wave_out()
        {
        hdr=NULL;
        buff=NULL;
        buffers=0;
        buff_size=0;
        _init=false;
        adr=0;
        num=0;
        err=0;
        event=wave_out_event;
        }
    ~wave_out()
        {
        _free();
        }
    wave_out(wave_out& a)   { *this=a; }
    wave_out* operator = (const wave_out *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //wave_out* operator = (const wave_out &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    void _free()
        {
        adr=0;
        num=0;
        if (_init) { waveOutClose(hw); _init=false; }
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        if (buff) for (int i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) mmap_del(buff[i]);
        if (buff) mmap_del(buff);
        if (hdr ) mmap_del(hdr );
        #endif
        if (buff)
            {
            for (int i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) delete[] buff[i];
            delete[] buff;
            buff=NULL;
            }
        if (hdr) { delete[] hdr; hdr=NULL; }
        }
    void init(DWORD _freq,WORD _chanels,WORD _bits,WORD _samples,WORD _buffers=10)
        {
        int i,ret;
        _free();
        buffers=_buffers;
        if (buffers<1) buffers=1;
        hdr=new WAVEHDR[buffers];
        buff=new BYTE*[buffers];
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        if (hdr ) mmap_new(hdr ,buffers*sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (buff) mmap_new(buff,buffers*sizeof(BYTE*));
        #endif

        freq    =_freq;
        chanels =_chanels;
        bits    =_bits;
        samples =_samples;
        buff_size=(chanels*bits*samples)>>3;
        samples=(buff_size<<3)/(chanels*bits);

        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++) buff[i]=new BYTE[buff_size];
        #ifdef _mmap_h
        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++) if (buff[i]) mmap_new(buff[i],buff_size);
        #endif

        buff_format.wFormatTag      =WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;       // set buffer format
        buff_format.nChannels       =chanels;
        buff_format.nSamplesPerSec  =freq;
        buff_format.wBitsPerSample  =bits;
        buff_format.cbSize          =0;
        buff_format.nAvgBytesPerSec =(freq*chanels*bits)>>3;
        buff_format.nBlockAlign     =(chanels*bits)>>3;
        if (event) ret=waveOutOpen(&hw,WAVE_MAPPER,&buff_format,(DWORD_PTR)event,(DWORD_PTR)this,CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
        else       ret=waveOutOpen(&hw,WAVE_MAPPER,&buff_format,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL);
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveOutGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            return;
            }
        WAVEHDR hdr0;
        hdr0.dwBufferLength=buff_size;
        hdr0.dwUser=0;
        hdr0.dwFlags=WHDR_INQUEUE;
        hdr0.dwLoops=0;
        hdr0.lpNext=NULL;
        for (i=0;i<buffers;i++)
            {
            hdr[i]=hdr0;
            hdr[i].lpData=buff[i];
            }
        _init=true;
        }
    void send(BYTE *data)
        {
        if (!_init) return;
        lock();

        if (num>buffers)
            {
            err++;
            adr=0;
            num=0;
            }

        DWORD i;
        int ret;
        BYTE *p;
        p=buff[adr];
        for (i=0;i<buff_size;i++) p[i]=data[i];
        ret=waveOutPrepareHeader(hw,&hdr[adr],sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveOutGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            unlock();
            return;
            }
        waveOutWrite(hw,&hdr[adr],sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (ret!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
//          waveOutGetErrorText(ret,err,255);
            unlock();
            return;
            }
        adr++;
        if (adr>=buffers) adr=0;
        num++;
        unlock();
        }
    void stop()
        {
        waveOutReset(hw);
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK wave_in_event(HWAVEIN hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2)
    {
    wave_in *w=(wave_in*)(void*)(DWORD_PTR)inst;
    if (w==NULL) return;
    if (msg==WIM_OPEN);             // open wave HW
    if (msg==WIM_DATA)              // wave data send done
        {
        int adr0=w->adr-w->num;
        while (adr0>=w->buffers) adr0-=w->buffers;
        while (adr0<          0) adr0+=w->buffers;
        if (w->onreceive) w->onreceive(w,w->buff[adr0],w->buff_size);
        w->num--;
        }                        
    if (msg==WIM_CLOSE);            // close wave HW
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK wave_out_event(HWAVEOUT hw,UINT msg,DWORD inst,DWORD p1,DWORD p2)
    {
    wave_out *w=(wave_out*)(void*)(DWORD_PTR)inst;
    if (w==NULL) return;
    w->lock();
    if (msg==WOM_OPEN);             // open wave HW
    if (msg==WOM_DONE) w->num--;    // wave data send done
    if (msg==WOM_CLOSE);            // close wave HW
    w->unlock();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

support file **lock.h:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Multithread lock class ver 1.00 ---------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _lock_h
#define _lock_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class single_lock
    {
public:
    CRITICAL_SECTION hnd;

    single_lock()                                   { InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&hnd,0x00000400); }
    ~single_lock()                                  { DeleteCriticalSection(&hnd); }
    single_lock(single_lock& a)                     { *this=a; }
    single_lock* operator = (const single_lock *a)  { *this=*a; return this; }
//  single_lock* operator = (const single_lock &a)  { **** }

    // thread safe functions
    inline void lock()      { EnterCriticalSection(&hnd); }
    inline void unlock()    { LeaveCriticalSection(&hnd); }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _multi_lock_size=16;                      // max number of simultanious access
class multi_lock
    {
public:
    CRITICAL_SECTION hnd;
    CRITICAL_SECTION dat[_multi_lock_size];
    DWORD adr0,adr1,siz;

    multi_lock()                                    { InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&hnd,0x00000400); for(int i=0;i<_multi_lock_size;i++) InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&dat[i],0x00000400); adr0=0; adr1=0; siz=0; }
    ~multi_lock()                                   { DeleteCriticalSection(&hnd); for(int i=0;i<_multi_lock_size;i++) DeleteCriticalSection(&dat[i]); }
    multi_lock(multi_lock& a)                       { *this=a; }
    multi_lock* operator = (const multi_lock *a)    { *this=*a; return this; }
//  multi_lock* operator = (const multi_lock &a)    { **** }

    // thread safe functions
    inline void lock()
        {
        EnterCriticalSection(&hnd);
        if (siz<_multi_lock_size)
            {
            siz++;
            EnterCriticalSection(&dat[adr1]);
            adr1++; if (adr1>=_multi_lock_size) adr1=0;
            }
//      else error();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&hnd);
        }
    inline void unlock()
        {
        EnterCriticalSection(&hnd);
        if (siz>0)
            {
            siz--;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&dat[adr0]);
            adr0++; if (adr0>=_multi_lock_size) adr0=0;
            }
//      else error();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&hnd);
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

support file **FIFO.h:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- FIFO template class ver 2.08 ------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _fifo_h
#define _fifo_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//static bool _enable_fifo_debug=false;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> class FIFO
    {
public:
    T *dat;
    int adr0,adr1,size;
    CRITICAL_SECTION lock;

    FIFO()                          { dat=NULL; InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&lock,0x00000400); alloc(16); }
    ~FIFO()                         { _free(); DeleteCriticalSection(&lock); }
    FIFO(FIFO& a)                   { *this=a; }
    FIFO* operator = (const FIFO *a){ *this=*a; return this; }
    FIFO* operator = (const FIFO &a){ EnterCriticalSection(&a.lock); EnterCriticalSection(&lock); _alloc(a.size); adr0=a.adr0; adr1=a.adr1; for (int i=0;i<size;i++) dat[i]=a.dat[i]; LeaveCriticalSection(&lock); LeaveCriticalSection(&a.lock); return this; }

    // already locked functions
    inline int  _adr_inc(int a)  volatile { a++; if (a>=size) a=0; return a; }
    inline int  _adr_dec(int a)  volatile { if (a!=adr0) a--; if (a<0) a=size-1; return a; }
    inline void _alloc(int _size)volatile { if (dat) delete[] dat; dat=NULL; size=_size; adr0=0; adr1=0; dat=new T[size]; if (dat==NULL) size=0; _reset(); }
    inline void _free()          volatile { if (dat) delete[] dat; dat=NULL; size=    0; adr0=0; adr1=0; }
    inline void _reset()         volatile { adr0=0; adr1=0; }
    inline void _in(T x)         volatile { if (_is_full()) return; dat[adr1]=x; adr1=_adr_inc(adr1); }
    inline T     _out()          volatile { if (_is_empty()){ T null; return null; } T x=dat[adr0]; adr0=_adr_inc(adr0); return x; }
    inline T     _peek_first()   volatile { if (_is_empty()){ T null; return null; } T x=dat[adr0]; return x; }
    inline T     _peek_last()    volatile { if (_is_empty()){ T null; return null; } int a=_adr_dec(adr1); T x=dat[a]; return x; }
    inline bool _is_empty()      volatile { bool ret=(adr0==adr1); return ret; }
    inline bool _is_full()       volatile { int a=_adr_inc(adr1); bool ret=(a==adr0); return ret; }
    inline int  _get_size()      volatile { if (_is_empty()) return 0; if (_is_full()) return size; if (adr0<adr1) return adr1-adr0; else return size+adr1-adr0; }

    // thread safe functions
    void _lock()            volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); }
    void _unlock()          volatile { LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); }
    void alloc(int _size)   volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock);        _alloc(_size); LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); }
    void reset()            volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock);        _reset();      LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); }
    void in(T x)            volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock);        _in(x);        LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); }
    T    out()              volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); T    x=_out();        LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    T    peek_first()       volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); T    x=_peek_first(); LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    T    peek_last()        volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); T    x=_peek_last();  LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    bool is_empty()         volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); bool x=_is_empty();   LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    bool is_full()          volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); bool x=_is_full();    LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    int  get_size()         volatile { EnterCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); int  x=_get_size();   LeaveCriticalSection((CRITICAL_SECTION*)&lock); return x; }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here simple usage (extracted from my generator hope I did not forget anything):

```cpp
// globals and init
const int _size=20*1024;
wave_out wo;
WORD buffer[_size]; // your PCM sound data matching the init operands
wo.init(44100,2,16,_size,10); // sampling_freq,channels,bits,buffer size,buffers

// this in some timer or thread (fast enbough)
while (wo.num<4)
 {
 // here prepare buff[] data 
 wo.send((BYTE*)buff); 
 }

// force to stop on app exit or when needed
wo.stop();
```

The stuff was compiled on BDS2006 C++ Builder so in case you use newer compiler you might need to tweak some stuff...had not time will to port this to new compiler yet so if the case see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72215338/2521214).

`wave_out` is for sound playback and `wave_in` is for recording both are using preferred windows sound device selected in control panel of Windows. To enable smooth playback just make sure that at least 4 buffers are filled in the sound que `while (wo.num<4)`... otherwise sound glitches might occur

You might also need to decode WAV files so here another ancient lib of mine **RIFF.h**:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- RIFF WAVE format: 1.01 ------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _RIFF_h
#define _RIFF_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 8bit PCM is unsigned
// 16bit PCM is signed 2'os complement little endian (big endian is RIFX)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _wave_chunk
    {
    DWORD ids;
    DWORD len;
    _wave_chunk(){ ids='    '; len=0; }
    _wave_chunk(_wave_chunk& a){ *this=a; }; ~_wave_chunk(){}; _wave_chunk* operator = (const _wave_chunk *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_wave_chunk* operator = (const _wave_chunk &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
struct _wave_hdr
    {
    DWORD ids;      // "RIFF"
    DWORD len;
    DWORD tps;      // "WAVE"
    _wave_hdr(){ ids='FFIR'; len=0; tps='EVAW'; }
    _wave_hdr(_wave_hdr& a){ *this=a; }; ~_wave_hdr(){}; _wave_hdr* operator = (const _wave_hdr *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_wave_hdr* operator = (const _wave_hdr &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
struct _wave_fmt
    {
    DWORD ids;      // "fmt "
    DWORD len;      // 16,18,40
    WORD  format;   // 1 = PCM linear quantization
/*                      0x0001  WAVE_FORMAT_PCM PCM
                        0x0003  WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT  IEEE float
                        0x0006  WAVE_FORMAT_ALAW    8-bit ITU-T G.711 A-law
                        0x0007  WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW   8-bit ITU-T G.711 µ-law
                        0xFFFE  WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE  Determined by SubFormat */
    WORD  chanels;
    DWORD samplerate;
    DWORD byterate;
    WORD  blockalign;
    WORD  bits;
    WORD  ext_len;  // extension length 0,22
    WORD  ext_validbits;
    DWORD ext_channelmask;
    BYTE  ext_subformat[16];
    _wave_fmt(){ ids=' tmf'; len=16; format=1; chanels=1; samplerate=44100; bits=8; ext_len=0; ext_validbits=0; ext_channelmask=0; for (int i=0;i<16;i++) ext_subformat[i]=0; compute(); }
    _wave_fmt(_wave_fmt& a){ *this=a; }; ~_wave_fmt(){}; _wave_fmt* operator = (const _wave_fmt *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_wave_fmt* operator = (const _wave_fmt &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    void compute()
        {
        byterate=(chanels*samplerate*bits)/8;
        blockalign=(chanels*bits)/8;
        }
    };
struct _wave_dat
    {
    DWORD ids;      // "data"
    DWORD len;
    _wave_dat(){ ids='atad'; len=0; }
    _wave_dat(_wave_dat& a){ *this=a; }; ~_wave_dat(){}; _wave_dat* operator = (const _wave_dat *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_wave_dat* operator = (const _wave_dat &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class wave
    {
public:
    AnsiString name;
    int hnd;
    bool readonly;
    _wave_hdr hdr;
    _wave_fmt fmt;
    _wave_dat dat;

    wave();
    ~wave();
    void create(AnsiString _name);
    void write(BYTE *data,DWORD size);

    bool open(AnsiString _name);
    DWORD read(BYTE *data,DWORD size);
    void close();
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
wave::wave()
    {
    name=0;
    hnd=-1;
    readonly=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
wave::~wave()
    {
    close();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void wave::create(AnsiString _name)
    {
    close();
    readonly=true;
//  hdr=_wave_hdr();
//  fmt=_wave_fmt();
//  dat=_wave_dat();
    hdr.len=sizeof(hdr)-8;
    dat.len=0;
    fmt.compute();
    name=_name;
    hnd=FileCreate(name);
    if (hnd<0) return;
    FileWrite(hnd,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    FileWrite(hnd,&fmt,fmt.len+8);
    FileWrite(hnd,&dat,sizeof(dat));
    readonly=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool wave::open(AnsiString _name)
    {
    close();
    readonly=true;
    name=_name;
    hnd=FileOpen(name,fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return false;
    if (FileRead(hnd,&hdr,sizeof(hdr))<sizeof(hdr)){ close(); return false; }
    if (hdr.ids!='FFIR') return false;
    if (hdr.tps!='EVAW') return false;
    _wave_chunk chk;
    DWORD sz=sizeof(chk),l;
    for(;;)
        {
        if (FileRead(hnd,&chk,sz)<sz){ close(); return false; }
            if (chk.ids==' tmf')
            {
            fmt.ids=chk.ids;
            fmt.len=chk.len;
            if (FileRead(hnd,((BYTE*)&fmt)+sz,chk.len)<chk.len){ close(); return false; }
            }
        else if (chk.ids=='atad')
            {
            dat.ids=chk.ids;
            dat.len=chk.len;
            return true;
            }
        else FileSeek(hnd,int(chk.len),1);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void wave::write(BYTE *data,DWORD size)
    {
    if (hnd<0) return;
    hdr.len+=size;
    dat.len+=size;
    if (!readonly) FileWrite(hnd,data,size);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD wave::read(BYTE *data,DWORD size)
    {
    if (hnd<0) return 0;
    return FileRead(hnd,data,size);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void wave::close()
    {
    name="";
    if (hnd<0) return;
    FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    if (!readonly) FileWrite(hnd,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=-1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And usage:**

```
// globals
wave wav;
wave_out wo;
BYTE *buff;

// init
wav.open("tetris2.wav"); // any file ...
wo.init(wav.fmt.samplerate,wav.fmt.chanels,wav.fmt.bits,dt*wav.fmt.samplerate/1000,10);
buff=new BYTE[wo.buff_size];

// timer 20ms ...
while (wo.num<4)
            {
            wav.read(buff,wo.buff_size);
            wo.send(buff);
            }

// exit
wo.stop();
wav.close();
delete[] buff;
```

the `wav.read(...)` returns number of BYTEs read so once it hit less than buffer size or even equals to zero it means you already on end of wavefile ... Now as you will have the wav in memory just rewrite the file access to memory access ...

Comment: thank you very much for the kindness, it shows there are people that are willing to help out in exceptional circumstances, a quality that seems to be disappearing.  I will add this to my project and with some luck it will do, as I expect it will. I will upload a working installation to my website soon so that people who care, can see what it is I am trying to do.  Cheers and thank you again

Answer (score 2):

[`PlaySound()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) cannot play audio from a stream.  It can play from a file, a block of memory, or an EXE/DLL resource.

I would not recommend storing your WAV audio in database blobs.  Use files or resources instead.  But, if you must use a database, you can use the `TDataSet::CreateBlobStream()` method to get a read-only `TStream` to access the blob data, and then you can `Read()` that data into an allocated memory buffer, or `CopyFrom()` it into a `TMemoryStream`, and then you can have `PlaySound()` play from the memory of that buffer/stream.

If you really need to play streaming audio, you will have to use [`waveOutOpen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutopen)/[`waveOutPrepareHeader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutprepareheader)/[`waveOutWrite()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutwrite) directly, or use more modern APIs like [DirectSound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee416960(v=vs.85)) or [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, due to my immediate situation, are you able to show how I could use these methods, I really do not have the time to do my own research on this, if PlaySound from file is the best to use, then that will need t do, cheers

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a code writing service.

Comment: Yes its is, I asked a question, you gave an answer, my reply is, I am not looking for a code writing service, I asked for assistant to shorten development time as a result of my terminal condition, but hey, that's ok, it's all good to know people are willing to help others in exceptional circumstances, have a nice day...