# Initialize and allocate size for 2D vector member variable using a member function at run-time

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, runtime, 2d

How to initialize and allocate size for 2D vector member variable using a member function at run-time?

Is there something wrong with this approach?

```
class A {

vector<vector<int>> m_matrix;

// trying to resize without using explicit resize
// using the constructor of 2D vectors at run time
// want the code to look simpler and avoid new/pointers
void initialize_matrix(int row, int column) {
  m_matrix = std::move(vector<vector<int>>(row, vector<int>(column, DEFAULT_VALUE)));
}
}
```

Comment: I would use `vector<vector<int>>(row, vector<int>(column, DEFAULT_VALUE)).swap(m_matrix);` rather than std::move.

Comment: Alexei Barnes: is there something wrong if I do it the way shown?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by wrong, that's a subjective question. For all intents and purposes however, you can use whatever method you like to construct and initialize members.

Comment: both solutions seem to achieve the result in constant time. thank you for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes** that will work fine. It uses `move` to guard against the compiler mistakenly using copy-assignment which is a nice touch.

You seem to be asking for suggestions though, so I'd suggest that `vector<vector<int>>` is a poor choice given that all the sub-`vector`s are the same size. You might consider using a single `vector`. I looked for an example of using a single `vector` to replace a `vector`-of-`vector`s and the simplest thing I could find on http://stackoverflow.com was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868317/2642059 There's a little bit better write up here though: http://upcoder.com/2/efficient-vectors-of-vectors