# Getting Error when reading file in string using C++Builder Project

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe

I want to read a whole file into a string. I am using Embarcadero C++Builder XE.

When I use the below code in my project, it is giving errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream in(Path);
std::string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::_Mutex::_Lock()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::_Mutex::_Unlock()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits::eq_int_type(const int&, const int&)' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits::not_eof(const int&)' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits::to_char_type(const int&)'
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits::eof()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits::to_int_type(const char&)' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::locale::id::operator unsigned int()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::locale::name() const' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::codecvt_base::codecvt_base(unsigned int)' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::locale::facet::_Incref()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::ios_base::ios_base()' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::ios_base::getloc() const' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::ctype::_Getcat(std::locale::facet * *, std::locale *)' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::ctype::widen(char) const' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::ios_base::rdstate() const' 
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

Any other solutions for reading a file into a string?

Comment: Check your library path. Maybe some configuration problem with your standard library.

Comment: @Devolus  :  Intsand of ifstream , Is there any soulution for reading file in Borland C++, RAD XE Embarcadero IDE ?

Comment: Your problem is not the standard library functions, it's your setup. As a sidenote, what you posted ist not a proper C++ code anyway, so you should post a full example anyway.

Comment: @Devolus : I have Written here code which is giving error. My goal is to create Function which read whole large file data and return file content in to string variable. Project is very large and old, So I can not do major change in configuration/setup at this moment.

Comment: You have a linker error clearly showing that your setup is not correct. If you don't want to change it, then you have to live with that error.

Comment: @Devolus  : Ok, How can i identify which configuration has problem? This is Project Configuration of Project:: [Project Config Photo](http://yourprintscreen.com?m=201706060915445936ab0080957)

Comment: Why using iostream and fstream in VCL?  You got `AnsiString` natively in VCL ... `TStrings` and `TMemo->Lines` can load entire text file with simple `LoadFromFile` method. File access is also simple use VCL:  `FileOpen/FileCreate, FileSeek, FileRead/FileWrite, FileClose`. But to your errors your project is wrongly configured so may be you got some weird settings or corruption in project file ... sometimes creating new one helps. `Unresolved external` means you have included header but no code nor linked obj/lib/dll where it is

Comment: @Spektre : Thank you very much. I am new in C++ VCL (Borland C++). Can you please give me Example in VCL for Reading a File and Save all content of File into String Variable, Please ?

Comment: @PratikMota added answer with some examples

Comment: @Spektre : Really Thank you very much for your effort. It really helps me.

Comment: @PratikMota glad to be of help. Use code insight to find out more functions (also CTRL+F1 context help is good ...) you want to use... most of VCL functions support AnsiString from rendering text to File routines ...  If you're new to Borland in case you are using BDS2006 or older take a look at this: [bds 2006 C hidden memory manager conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214) to avoid future headaches. Using CodeGuard in project options is cool for debugging...

Comment: @Spektre : I am using Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE Version . Also Project is using VCL Library.

Comment: The code shown works fine for me in XE2.  No linker errors.  I would have used `std::istream_iterator` instead of `std::istreambuf_iterator`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets create an empty **VCL** Form app and add a single `TMemo` control on it. The **IDE** will name it `Memo1` automatically . The Memo object is a Text editor with 2 important properties:

1. **`Memo1->Text`**

   `Text` is a `System::String` (automatically reallocable string class from **VCL** holding the whole text of the memo. `String` has a `Length()` function returning number of characters present, and each character is accessed using the `[]` operator like this (indexed from 1 !!!):

   ```
   String s = _D("123456"); // set some string to s
   int l = s.Length(); // get its length
   for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) s[i] = '0'; // change all the chars to zeros
   Memo1->Text = s; // feed it to Memo
   ```

   There are tons of support functions inside `String`, the most important for you is formatted output:

   ```
   Memo1->Text = String().sprintf(_D("float number: %7.3f"), float(123.456));
   ```

   You can use `String` as your local variables, too:

   ```
   String s = _D("some text");
   Memo1->Text = s;
   ```

   Also for backward compatibility, if you need a `char*` for some functions, then just assign the `String` to an `AnsiString` and call its `c_str()` method:

   ```
   String s = _D("some text");
   AnsiString as = s;
   char *txt = as.c_str();
   ```

   But beware not to overwrite unallocated space, or use that pointer after any reallocation inside `as`, or after `as` goes out of scope. This is used mainly as input parameter for Win32 API functions, C functions, non-VCL LIBs/DLLs, etc.
2. **`Memo1->Lines`**

   This is a `TStrings` class, which holds a dynamic array of `String`s. In a TMemo, each element represents a line in the `Text`. You can dynamically add lines to `Memo1` like this:

   ```
   Memo1->Lines->Add(_D("text 1"));
   Memo1->Lines->Add(_D("text 2"));
   Memo1->Lines->Add(_D("text 3"));
   ```

   You can load/save the whole Memo contents like this:

   ```
   Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile("file1.txt");
   Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile("file1.txt");
   ```

   Any change in `Memo1->Lines` will also change `Memo1->Text`, and vice versa, as they both represent the same thing. You can have your Memo hidden (invisible) and still use it in case you do not want to show what are you doing ...

You can also load an entire file into a `char[]` buffer using file access functions without any **VCL** component, like this:

```
int hnd = FileOpen("file1.txt", fmOpenRead); // open file hnd>=0 if all OK
int siz = FileSeek(hnd, 2, 0); // point to end of file and return position = file size
FileSeek(hnd, 0, 0); // point back to start of file
char *txt = new char[siz+1] // allocate space for text and null terminator
FileRead(hnd, txt, siz); // load the file into memory at once
FileClose(hnd); // close file as we do not need it anymore

txt[siz] = 0; // add null termination just to be safe (text files do not contains zeros usually)
// do your thing with txt[siz]

delete[] txt;
```

Or:

```
TFileStream *strm = new TFileStream("file1.txt", fmOpenRead); // open file
int siz = strm->Size; // file size
char *txt = new char[siz+1] // allocate space for text and null terminator
strm->ReadBuffer(txt, siz); // load the file into memory at once
delete strm; // close file as we do not need it anymore

// do your thing with txt[siz]

delete[] txt;
```

Or:

```
TMemoryStream *strm = new TMemoryStream;
strm->LoadFromFile("file1.txt"); // open file

// do your thing with strm->Memory up to strm->Size bytes...

delete strm;
```

Unlike `std::fstream`, these will work for any file ... even if holding control codes.

Comment: "*`Text` is `AnsiString`*" - no, it is not. It is a `System::String`, and in C++Builder 2009 and later, which includes XE, `System::String` is an alias for `System::UnicodeString`, not for `System::AnsiString`.  As such, `char *txt = Memo1->Text.c.str();` will not compile (and it is dangerous anyway, as `txt` will be left pointing to invalid memory when the statement is complete). Also, `Memo1->Text[i]='0';` has no effect on the Memo, since it is modifying a temp `String` object returned by the `Text` getter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it should be `c_str()` of coarse nice catch but yore right `Text` property is not the same as `AnsiString` I am biased by my use of BCB and BDS and no experience with XE. will repair my mistake shortly

Comment: "*You can have your Memo hidden (invisible) and still use it in case you do not want to show what are you doing*" - use the `TStringList` class for that instead. Don't use visual controls for non-visual work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what does `_D("")` ? it is some kind of support macro for `System::String` constants ? or it is to preserve unicode ?

Comment: it is a support macro, yes. It ensures the literal uses the same charset encoding that `System::String` and `System::Char` use (currently UTF-16 in 2009+). It is similar to the `_T()` macro in the C standard lib for `_TCHAR` literals, and the `TEXT()` macro in the Win32 API for `TCHAR` literals.