# Helpfile (*.chm) file not opening within embarcadero application

Tags: c++builder, chm, c++builder-xe, helpfile

**Problem**

I am using **Embarcadero C++ Builder XE**.
I am trying to trigger the opening of a help file (*.chm), when the user presses the F1 button on their keyboard.
I thought I had done everything correctly, but I get no response/action when F1 is pressed.

**What I did:**

I have created a .chm help file (using Microsoft HTML Help Workshop).
I have copied the compiled .chm file to the application directory.
I have set:

```
Application->HelpFile = "My_Help.chm";
```

In the main form, I have set the HelpFile property to the same .chm file.

In the main form I have included the following two lines of code:

```
#include "HtmlHelpViewer.hpp"
#pragma link "HTMLHelpViewer"
```

The confusing thing is: I had this working a few weeks ago, and subsequently 'lost' the code :(

And since then, when I went to recreate the solution, I have had no success.

**Also**

If I define a help button, as detailed here ( [embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Showing_Help_with_Help_Buttons) ), still nothing happens.

However, if I attach the following code to a button, the help file DOES open:

```
Application->HelpContext(0);
```

**Question**

Has anybody any idea why this would have worked before, but now it doesn't?
Perhaps there is a simple step I did in the past and have forgotten, but I have searched all the help on this that I can find (including here at [helpscribble](https://www.helpscribble.com/delphi-bcb.html)), and covered all the steps as I see it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

(I tried posting on the Embarcadero forums but that is a complete waste of time at the moment)

Comment: In particular, do you have the CHM file in a local directory? I have heard of some problems with chm and Windows 10 updates.

Comment: I'll think you'll find there's some sort of security restriction on the CHM. Once you approve it, the HTML help file opens successfully. I recall a work colleague having such an issue. Also had issues emailing them too..

Comment: Maybe it depends on what you entered into the helpcontext/keyword fields of the form?

Comment: help-info: I have tried the CHM in local directory, and other directories. Also, I am using Windows 7, not 10.
JGFMK: I don't know how to check the security restriction on CHM files but if this was a possibility then any user who installs my application would haver to jump through the same hoops which would be ridiculous.
Marco: I have tried about 10 different CHM files - mine, and standard ones that come and work with other applications.
All: I keep coming back to this fact: I had it working on my PC, with my application - then lost the code and tried to do it all again.

Comment: @garrettB I must have overlooked the "lost code" part. I got the impression that your code worked and only after upgrading win it had stopped (In which case my answer would be relevant). But clearly that is not the case so ignore my answer (I deleted it) . The only thing I can think of without seeing the code/hierarchy/organization of your App is that either you are overriding VCL events somwhere or more likely have a memory access error/leak overwriting VCL code (did happen to me few times in the past causing weird behavior without any errors/exceptions thrown)

Comment: @Spektre: I wondered if anything else in my project was interfering with the F1 help function, so I created a new project, added the headers and pragma statements, and defined the help file, as above - but still F1 Help did not work. Then I defined a button, with code "Application->HelpContext(10010);;" and this did work. So again, something basic is wrong :(

Comment: @garrettB well I can only speculate like mistakenly overwritten VCL code (damaging the VCL lib) or Corrupted registry or installed some weird toolbar/actievex/trojan or any virus that taps into keyboard messages (especially those scanning for passwords). It can be also memory leak. I am on older builder and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214) solved me a lot of unrelated errors and weird behavior but I doubt its the case... If you got CodeGuard in your App try to enable it to check for hidden problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience in help authoring but I'm not a C++ programmer. Nevertheless, the C++ Builder Community Edition is installed on my Windows10 PC.

My SDIForm has following code snippet:

```
#include "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer.hpp"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer"
```

I copied the CHM file (CHM-example.chm) into the build directories for simplification (Base, Debug and Release). It is working for me.

My resulting HTMLHelp Viewer window:

[image]

```
void __fastcall TSDIAppForm::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Application->HelpContext(10000);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TSDIAppForm::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  ShowMessage("The form has been created");
  Application->HelpFile = "CHM-example.chm";
}
```

After deleting the CHM file (CHM-example.chm) in the three directories mentioned above I tried following steps from the docs - this is working too. But please note I had to delete following code (see screenshot):

```
Application->HelpFile = "CHM-example.chm";
```

The usual way to designate the main help file for an application is using the HelpFile property of the global Application object.

Open the Project Options dialog box (Project > Options) and select the Appearance page (under Application). In the Help file option, specify the help file. Click Browse. By default, the Application Help File dialog box shows only files with the .hlp extension. To specify other types of help files, select the Any file (*.*) type in the Files of type control. Then you will be able to select help files of types such as .CHM, .HTML, and others.

This option sets the Application.HelpFile property. This property defines the main help file to the application. When the application receives any help-handling command, it, by default, uses this help file to execute the help command.

To specify an individual help file for a particular form, you can use the HelpFile property of this form.

Comment: help-info.de: I think you are just repeating the steps that I took? I don't see anything new here.

Comment: @garrettB: My CHM file [see HTMLHelp Download section](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh.htm) is checked for the context ID. This can be a problem in your CHM files depending on your experience in CHM generation related to the context-ID (just a hint). The following code snippet `#include "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer.hpp"` is different and "It is working for me ..." with some steps is the message. Really lost the context-sensitive help code for many controls?

Comment: I am using your help file with no success. I have ALWAYS been able to open the help file with a button click, but right now I cannot open the help file using the F1 key.
The reason you use "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer.hpp" directive and I use "HTMLHelpViewer.hpp" is because my Embarcadero version (C++ XE Builder) does not use the VCL scope name, but in subsequent versions (from XE2 onwards) HtmlHelpViewer belongs to the "Vcl" unit scope

Answer (score 0):

**Discoveries and a Workaround**

I have made a few discoveries, and have come up with a work-around for now, until I learn more about this subject

**DISCOVERY ONE**

The HelpContext value seems to work if it is non-zero and valid (i.e. the ID is defined in the CHM file).

- If I enter a non-zero and valid value, then the help file will open
  up (on the correct page) when I press F1 I am (almost) sure that a
  zero value used to work before - it would open the help file on the
  first / default page

**DISCOVERY TWO**

My main application (and I should have thought about this AND mentioned it before), consists of one form which contains a large number of frames. The main form holds a navigation menu and a frame holder space, and the frames are like 'pages' that the user can navigates to.

So, once I got to Discovery one (non-zero ContextHelp value), I noticed that the help file opened up on the same page, regardless of which frame was being displayed - even though I defined different HelpContext values for each frame.

So the HelpContext value of each frame does not seem to make a difference.
I wonder if this is due to the fact that there are several frames overlayed at the same position, and the user navigation effectively involves making one frame visible and the previous frame invisible. However, Discovery Three makes me think otherwise.

**DISCOVERY THREE**

On one of the frames (‘pages’), I defined the following components: TGroupBox, TPanel, TStaticText, TCheckbox, TMemo and TButton

- The ContextHelp values for the TGroupBox, TPanel and TStaticText
  components have no effect.
- The ContextHelp values for the TCheckbox,
  TMemo and TButton components DO work

So it looks like the ContextHelp only works for interactive components – components that respond visibly to a click

Which is why I think ContextHelp values would never work for TFrame components.

**DISCOVERY FOUR**

I have a number of popup forms that are created and deleted on the fly throughout the use of the application. The ContextHelp values defined for these forms DO work.

**WORK AROUND**

I defined only non-zero and valid ContextHelp values for each form, including the main form

I defined a toolbar menu item (which I made invisible), and assigned the F1 shortcut to it. Now, when F1 is pressed, this menu’s OnClick event is run first, and then the regular OnHelp handling is called.

In the menu’s OnClick event, I determine which frame is currently ‘active’ (visible), and assign the desired ContextHelp value to the main form. Then the regular OnHelp handling is called, and uses this freshly assigned ContextHelp value to open the help file on the desired page.

**FINALLY**

I am reasonably happy with the workaround, as it requires me to list all the ContextHelp values in one function – which I was going to do for the frames anyway – for clarity and ease of maintenance.