# Thread safety of AnsiString reference counting mechanism

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

My question is about AnsiString in Borland C++Builder 6.0
As you know, VCL's AnsiString uses reference counting.
Is that reference counting thread safe?
For example, suppose we have `std::queue<AnsiString> asq;`
We push an AnsiString value in that queue in thread#1, and then we do `asq.pop()` in thread#2. (The access to `asq` itself is synchronized.) Strings are not modified. 
Is it possible I will have a memory leak when AnsiString's destructor is called when using AnsiString(s) that way?

Comment: `AnsiString`s are thread safe However you might encounter a memory leak in it ... if the case its most likely related to this [bds 2006 C hidden memory manager conflicts (class new / delete vs. AnsiString)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17698102/2521214) compiler bug instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the refcount is thread-safe.  The RTL places a lock on the refcount whenever it is being incremented and decremented. There will not be any memory leak in the scenario you describe.