# Upgrade old C++ Builder 5.0 Projects to new Version (10) - experiences

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a lot of very old Borland C++Builder 5.0 projects, and want to upgrade to the latest Embarcadero version.

As I know, the newest version does not import such old `.bpr` projects, so that I must reconfigure it by hand.

My idea is to temporarily install an older version of C++Builder that has such an import and use it to convert the projects, then I could load them in the newest version.

Does anybody know which C++Builder version I can use that works with both project file formats?

Does anybody have any experiences with such a conversion? Are the `.dfm` and resource files compatible?

Comment: Importing old projects to newer IDEs rarely works seamlessly, in any version. You are better off simply creating new projects fresh and adding your existing source files to them as needed. And yes, DFMs and resources are largely still compatible (of course, there have been changes over the years). Just note that going from BCB5 to RS10.4 is a HUGE jump, so be prepared for a lot of migration headaches. Make sure you read https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center

Comment: upgrading existing project files directly in IDE is suicidal especially for complex projects. Even if it works it tends to break in time causing weird anoying IDE bugs. As Remy wrote is much more safer to create new empty project and copy the stuff from old project and add it to new one. However I encountered some problems even then (some forms I had to create from scratch) but that is rare ... IIRC Beware some `AnsiString` member functions behavior changed between BCB5 and BDS2006 so in newer versions like RAD it will be probably too...

Comment: Also After my upgrade from BCB5 I encouneterd this compiler/linker/CppEngine problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214 took me years to get to bottom of this among others like `for (;;;)` ...