# Memory Leak profiler for borland c++ builder

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, memory-profiling, borland-c++

How do we check memory leaks and performance issues in the application built with Borland C++ builder?

Comment: this may help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/22168731/2521214 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/20565511/2521214 especially the last one solved a lot for me)